# Changing the addClass in a javascript function to be called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the function below:

```
var players = function(){
  var $div = $('<div>').attr('id', 'prompt');
  var $input = $('<input>').attr('class', 'player' + playerNames);
  var $p = $('<p>').attr('class', 'player' + playerNames).html("Enter First Player" );
  $div.append($input).append($p);
  $('.container').append($div);

  $('input').keydown(function(e) { 
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
      $div.addClass('move-left').removeAttr('id');
      playerOne = $input.val();
      $p.html($input.val())
      $input.remove();
    }
  });
}
```

I want to call this function twice in a row.

I want the `.addClass('move-left')` to be `addClass('move-right')` playerNames which `starts at 0 to be 1` and finally for the "*Enter First Player*" to be "Enter Second Player".

Do I need a `for`? 
if so does it have to wrap the entire *function*?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: use `hasClass()` to check if `.addClass('move-left')` has occurred and if it has then `addClass('move-right')`  -- okay after your edit im not sure what your after in the rest of your question

Comment: players function creates a div that takes an input from the user then transitions left. After that happens I want the processes repeated again only this time after the second user input, the div transitions right. Is there a way to do this without copy and pasting the function?

Comment: yes create it abstractly and pass in variables to it.

Answer (score 2):

What about passing those things as parameters to the function? And, perhaps instead of playerOne being closed over, make a local variable that you declare and return

```js
var players = function(promptStr, classStr){
  var $div = $('<div>').attr('id', 'prompt');
  var $input = $('<input>').attr('class', 'player' + playerNames);
  var $p = $('<p>').attr('class', 'player' + playerNames).html(promptStr );
  $div.append($input).append($p);
  $('.container').append($div);
  var playerX = {name:null};

  $('input').keydown(function(e) { 
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
      $div.addClass(classStr).removeAttr('id');
      playerX.name = $input.val();
      $p.html($input.val())
      $input.remove();
    }
  });
 
  return playerX;
}

var playerOne = players("Ready Player One", "move-left");
var playerTwo = players("Enter Player Two", "move-right");
```

Comment: I made a small mistake, returning playerX like that won't work. You can make playerX be an object {player:null} and return that, then set playerX.player in the keydown callback.

Or use a promise.

Comment: Now that code is creating three divs simultaneously and I was tying to have just two divs pop up one after the other. Thats what Im trying to figure out :)

Answer (score 0):

With an if statement

```
 $('input').keydown(function(e) { 
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        if ($div.hasClass('move-left') {
            $div.addClass('move-right').removeAttr('id');
        } else {
            $div.addClass('move-left').removeAttr('id');
        }
        playerOne = $input.val();
        $p.html($input.val())
        $input.remove();
    }
  });
```